# Get Prisoner visitor count

Tags: mysql

Tables look like so:

```
Person
first_name
middle_name
last_name
person_ssn

Prisoner
person_ssn
prisoner_id

Visitation
visitor_id
prisoner_id

visitor
visitor_id
first_name
last_name
```

I'm interested in getting a prisoners name and how many visitors they have.

What i've got so far:

```
select person.first_name, person.middle_name, person.last_name, count(visitor_id) AS visitorCount
from prisoner
inner join person on prisoner.person_ssn = person.person_ssn
inner join visitation on prisoner.prisoner_id = visitation.prisoner_id;
```

This seems to only result in a single prisoner

Comment: If you're interested in getting a prisoners name then why are you selecting a persons name? Are you asking us to do your homework again FP?

Answer (score 1):

You need a `group by` clause.  Otherwise, your query is an aggregation query that returns one row.

```
select person.first_name, person.middle_name, person.last_name, count(visitor_id) AS visitorCount
from prisoner
inner join person on prisoner.person_ssn = person.person_ssn
inner join visitation on prisoner.prisoner_id = visitation.prisoner_id
group by person.first_name, person.middle_name, person.last_name;
```

Comment: You're right, I needed the group by clause. Cheers!